# How to add css class of new records in the table html, data is stored in Mysql?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Title is not entirely clear what is required if more detail is:
In mysql db table has, from it to the page of data is displayed in html table this code:

```
<?php            
   $db_host = 'localhost';         
   $db_name = 'DB';         
   $db_username = 'NAME';         
   $db_password = 'PASS';       
   $db_table_to_show = 'TABLE';         
   $connect_to_db = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_password) 
   or die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());           
   mysql_select_db($db_name, $connect_to_db)      
   or die("Could not select DB: " . mysql_error());   
   mysql_set_charset("utf8");          
   $qr_result = mysql_query("select * from " . $db_table_to_show)      
   or die(mysql_error());            
   echo '<table id="table">';       
   echo '<thead>';         
   echo '<tr>';
   echo '<th class="table-fandom">fandom</th>';        
   echo '<th>author</th>';     
   echo '<th class="table-name">name</th>';
   echo '<th>size</th>';    
   echo '<th class="table-status">status</th>';             
   echo '<th>date</th>';       
   echo '<th>tags</th>';
   echo '</tr>';       
   echo '</thead>';        
   echo '<tbody>';         

   while($data = mysql_fetch_array($qr_result)){       
       echo '<tr>';
       echo '<td>' . $data['fandom'] . '</td>';    
       echo '<td>' . $data['author'] . '</td>';         
       echo '<td><a href="/goto/' . $data['url'] . '" target="_blank">' . $data['name'] . '</a><div class="menu" style="display: none;"><br> '                                             . $data['annotation'] .  '  </div></td>';       
       echo '<td>' . $data['size'] . '</td>';  
       echo '<td>' . $data['status'] . '</td>';        
       echo '<td>' . $data['date'] . '</td>';  
       echo '<td>' . $data['tags'] . '</td>';                  
       echo '</tr>';       
   }       

   echo '</tbody>';        
   echo '</table>';         
   mysql_close($connect_to_db);        
  ?>
```

Requires that the new records that were added today, has been assigned a special css class within 72 hours.
PS Sorry for my english, it's not my native language.

Comment: Which thing you want to add css class to the table or to the whole row which is added today means tr of the row added today or every td of row which is added today?

Comment: add something like this `if($date['frommysql'] == $currentDate)`

Comment: @Neeraj Kumar
I want to add a class to the tr.
But it is possible to td, like author.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to add registration time in table. For example you save registration time in unix timestamp. Then you need to use condition after while loop.

```
 while($data = mysql_fetch_array($qr_result))
 { 
    if($data['registration_time'] > strtotime("-3 days") ) 
    {
      echo '<tr class="change_color_class">';
    }
    else
    {
          echo '<tr class="normal_class">';
    }        
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
...
 while($data = mysql_fetch_array($qr_result)){     
      if($data['date'] > date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-3 days'))  
          echo '<tr class="new">';
      else
          echo '<tr>';

      echo '<td>' . $data['fandom'] . '</td>';    
      echo '<td>' . $data['author'] . '</td>';         
      echo '<td><a href="/goto/' . $data['url'] . '" target="_blank">' .         $data['name'] . '</a><div class="menu" style="display: none;"><br> '         . $data['annotation'] .  '  </div></td>';       
      echo '<td>' . $data['size'] . '</td>';  
      echo '<td>' . $data['status'] . '</td>';        
      echo '<td>' . $data['date'] . '</td>';  
      echo '<td>' . $data['tags'] . '</td>';                  
      echo '</tr>';       
    }
```